# JS - surroundContents only retains highlight on text about 20% of the highlight attempts

Tags: javascript, highlighting

I am using a mouseup event to trigger a function which highlights text and surrounds the highlighted text with a span (function from stack overflow):

```
function highlightText(e) {

    var t = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (t) {
        $("#mySpan").remove();
        var range   = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            newNode = document.createElement("span");
        newNode.id  = 'mySpan';

        range.surroundContents(newNode);

    }
}
```

The main problem I am encountering is that as long as `surroundContents` is included, the text remains highlighted only about 20% of the highlight attempts (otherwise highlighting disappears immediately). I tried adding a setTimeout, not calling surroundContent for 1s. I also tried removing the remove() statement, but still no good.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: what about beginning the function with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I included this right after and before surroundContents call but to no avail.

Comment: Did you tried using "TextHighlighter" from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/)?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem with Chromium on Android. In some specific cases, the call of `range.surroundContents(newNode)` would cause a very weird behaviour of page reload and so on. After checking [the documentation of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents):

> This method is nearly equivalent to
>   newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
>   range.insertNode(newNode). After surrounding, the boundary points of
>   the range include newNode.

So the obvious thing was to apply another way highlight the text. I found [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) library which did exactly what I wanted without that annoying side effect. (Here's a [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/sohaybh/3LhL3jok/) that shows how it's used to highlight just selection). The difference is that library was not using `range.surroundContents(newNode)` nor `newNode.appendChild` but rather `node.replaceChild`.

Based on that, here's the solution to the problem I was having and I think it applies to your case as well.

```
function surroundRangeWithSpan(range) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');

    // The text is within the same node (no other html elements inside of it)
    if (range.startContainer.isEqualNode(range.endContainer) && range.startContainer.childNodes.length == 0) {
      // Here you customise your <span> element
      customSurroundContents(range, span);
    } else {
      // Here you have to break the selection down
    }
    return span;
  }

  function customSurroundContents(range, span) {
    var node = range.commonAncestorContainer;
    var startNode = node.splitText(range.startOffset);
    var ret = startNode.splitText(range.toString().length);
    span.textContent = startNode.textContent;
    startNode.parentNode.replaceChild(span, startNode);
  }
```

And you pass `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)` to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause of the failure is the selected text encompasses only the beginning or the ending of a non-text node, and not both of them.

So if were to run that code only selecting "This is Bo" in the following it will fail (and throw an exception) because it doesn't also capture the closing tag in the selection:

```
This is <em>bold</em>
```

So ending up with:

```
This is <em>bo
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents